# query mongodb using node and facebook token

Tags: node.js, mongodb, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am using the Facebook SDK on a mobile app. After the login, I get a token (long string) from facebook. I want to use this to connect to a remove mongodb database and update or query the database there.

Am I correct in understanding that:

1. I need to run node.js on the remote server and then
2. make a connection from the app to the remote node.js, and then
3. have node.js query the mongodb

If yes, can someone please point me to a simple example that demonstrates this?

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution which is in line with what I need: http://www.quietless.com/kitchen/building-a-login-system-in-node-js-and-mongodb/

Answer (score 0):

What you require is API(mostly REST which understands JSON), much like the Facebook api your mobile app is already talking to. Your mobile app will also communicate with this API, which in turn connects to MongoDB and preforms desired operation.

Look [here](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/a-beginners-guide-to-http-and-rest--net-16340) to get basic understanding of REST API

Look [here](http://thejavanode.wordpress.com/2014/11/13/building-a-simple-rest-api-using-node-js-restify-js-and-mongodb-mongoose-js-part-2-creating-server/) for sample REST API implementation using nodejs.